# I am not getting the properly i get "0" instead even though it is stored properly in the database,

Tags: php, laravel, events

here is the controller i am creating new room,i dd($attr)and i am having the proper id there

```php
 public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $attr = Validator($request->all(), [
            'topic' => ['string'],
            'size'  => ['required','integer'],
            'language_id'   => ['required', 'exists:languages,id']
        ]);

        if($attr->fails()){
            return response($attr->errors(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        
        $attr = $attr->validated();

        $attr = Arr::add($attr, 'id', uniqid());
        $attr = Arr::add($attr, 'owner_id', auth()->id());

        $data =  Room::create($attr)->toArray();
        // fire room created event
        broadcast(new NewRoomCreatedEvent($data));

        return response($data, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

I am getting this error in postman
[image]
and also here is the event

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Room;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewRoomCreatedEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $room;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($room)
    {
        $this->room = $room;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('practice4free');
    }
}
```

I do not know how to fix it, and also why I am not getting the proper id that is stored in the database instead I am getting "0".

Comment: Post code, not images.

Comment: how is this 'id' field defined in the schema?

Comment: `$table->string('id')->index()->unique();`

Comment: i added also this to the model itself `protected $keyType = 'string';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the refresh eloquent function like that

```php
 public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $attr = Validator($request->all(), [
            'topic' => ['string'],
            'size'  => ['required','integer'],
            'language_id'   => ['required', 'exists:languages,id']
        ]);

        if($attr->fails()){
            return response($attr->errors(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        
        $attr = $attr->validated();

        $attr = Arr::add($attr, 'id', uniqid());
        $attr = Arr::add($attr, 'owner_id', auth()->id());

        $data =  Room::create($attr);

        $data = $data->refresh();
        $data = $data->load('language');
        // fire room created event
        broadcast(new NewRoomCreatedEvent($data));

        return response($data, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

but is that alright, coz it is weird that I am not getting the id even though it is stored in the database.